# Dynamic Google Column Chart

Tags: javascript, php

I want to create a google column chart dynamically. My database  query result is
`[{"month":"May-2013","total_sales":"1369250"},{"month":"June-2013","total_sales":"4328119"},{"month":"July-2013","total_sales":"4636663"},{"month":"August-2013","total_sales":"4754047"},{"month":"September-2013","total_sales":"5014683"}]`

I want to show these json data as google column chart.Plese help me..Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
[
    ['Month','Sales'],
    ['May-2013','1369250'],
    ['August-2013','4754047']
]
```

Your data needs to be in a similar format, please refer to [this](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart).

Comment: i wanat to show it dynamically.when data are added, it will change dynamically my sql query is `$query="SELECT  DATE_FORMAT(last_update,'%M-%Y') AS month,SUM(bill_amount) as total_sales FROM `spl_sale_ledger`  group by MONTH(last_update) order by last_update";`